# An underflow question

Tags: arrays, overflow

> c: 
>     [ 11579208,
>       92373161954235,
>       70985008687907,
>       85326998466564,
>       5640394575840,
>       7913129639935 ]

When I "underflow" a unchecked balance of coins, I get the array of numbers instead of a -1.

Edit: Might be a two's complement, will calculate it.

Any explanation are welcome, I do get that an unsigned integer can not be negative.

Answer (score 2):

OK got it, will still leave it as a reference for other lost ones like me.

A 256 bit number is really big, I decided to change it to an 8 bit unsigned integer to test.

When I underflow it, we get 255

> c: [ 255 ]

Converting 255 to binary would give us 1111 1111 and to hex is FF.

In conclusion, we can say that it is a two's complement of 0000 0001 to explain it.

A 256 bit number is pretty damn big.